# Modifying a managed object fetched from an NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

OK, so I'm having a go at building a Mac OS X app using Core Data.

The basic layout is that there is a main window containing a `NSTableView`, which displays a brief description of all objects managed by the app; the entities are simple, containing a few fields like a title, date, and notes. The main window provides commands to add, delete, and modify entries. When adding or modifying an entry, the app displays a new window that has all the properties of that object available to edit.

The editor window lives in its own .nib, is managed by a subclass of `NSWindowController`, and is loaded via a `[[SUBCLASS alloc] initWithWindowNibName:]` call. The editable fields in this window are bound to an `NSObjectController`, which will manage a single entry out of the list. This controller is not bound to anything out of the nib; when this controller gets loaded, its `managedObjectContext` and `content` values are set to the main object context and the entity being edited, respectively.

So, adding an object works great, and works like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [[self.managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey: @"LogEntryEntity"];
LogEntryEntity *entry = (LogEntryEntity *) [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity: entityDesc
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext];
LogEditorController *editor = [[LogEditorController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"LogEditorWindow"
    logEntry: entry];
entry.date = [NSDate dateOneHourAgoTo30Minutes];
[editor setSaveHandler: ^(LogEditorController *c)
 {
     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![self.managedObjectContext save: &error])
         NSLog(@"Failed to save object: %@", error);
     [self.logTableView reloadData];
 }];
[entry release];
[editor loadWindow];
[editor showWindow: self];
```

Delete works, too:

```
NSIndexSet *selectedIndexes = [self.logTableView selectedRowIndexes];
if ([selectedIndexes count] == 0)
    return;
[self.logArrayController removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes: selectedIndexes];
if (![self.managedObjectContext save: &error])
    NSLog(@"error saving: %@", error);
```

But when I go to edit a selected entry:

```
NSIndexSet *selectedIndexes = [self.logTableView selectedRowIndexes];
if ([selectedIndexes count] != 1)
    return;

LogEntryEntity *entry = (LogEntryEntity *) [[self.logArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex: [selectedIndexes firstIndex]];
LogEditorController *editor = [[LogEditorController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"LogEditorWindow"
    logEntry: entry];
[editor setSaveHandler: ^(LogEditorController *c)
 {
     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![self.managedObjectContext save: &error])
         NSLog(@"error saving: %@", error);
 }];
[editor loadWindow];
[editor showWindow: self];
```

What happens here, though, is that when the window appears, the fields are filled out with the contents of the correct entry. **But**, immediately after, all the fields get set to the values of some *other* entry (perhaps not coincidentally, it gets set to the one with the smallest objectID of all objects), and I can confirm when the window closes that the `content` value of the `NSObjectController` has changed to that different entity. When I first set `content`, I've confirmed that it is the one I want to edit.

What's going on here? I mean, it's clear that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see from this code how the `editor` window could switch `LogEntryEntity` objects unless you have some other code or have bound the editor window incorrectly. You are passing a specific object and not an array of objects so how does the `editor` window even find the other objects to incorrectly display?

I would suggest removing the cast from this line:

```
LogEntryEntity *entry = (LogEntryEntity *) [[self.logArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex: [selectedIndexes firstIndex]];
```

... because if for some reason the object returned from the array is not actual a `LogEntryEntity` object, you will never know. It could be another managedObject or something else entirely. Cast in Objective-C are very powerful and the compiler, of course, trust them implicitly.